# How do you use a PHP function to strip comments out of a file, stylesheet or javascript?

Tags: php, css

I have a large commented file ( /* css comment style */ ) which needs to be cleansed of comments and later to have blank lines and other unnecessary baggage removed. The trouble I am having is that when I pass the variable for the file into the function that it returns 0 bytes. The example:

```
<?php

function minify($data) {
  global $data;  
  $data = preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $data); // CSS comments
  $data = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t", '  ', '    ', '    '), '', $data); 
  return ($data);
}

function minify2($data) {
  global $data;
  return ($data);
}

ob_start();
include ("$file");
$style = ob_get_clean(); // grabs the file contents into the $style variable - verified

/* FILE OPERATIONS */

# $style = preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $style); // CSS comments; works SUCCESSFULLY if run inline

#$style = minify($style); // FAILS

$style = minify2($style); // FAILS

$fpi = fopen("out.css", "w");

fwrite($fpi, "$style");

?>
```

I verified that $style is not empty be echoing it to the screen. If I execute the regex expression inline as you see above (commented out) it works perfectly; executing it within the function is the problem. I also tried a really elemental experiment, minify2, which also fails to return #data. Is there something really simple that I am missing?

Edited addendum:

Rather than using ob_start and ob_get_clean to get the file into the variable I also used the following commenting out ob_start ...:

```
#$style = file_get_contents("$file");

#$style = include ("$file");
```

In all 3 cases the variable is good. If I run the regex inline:

```
$style = preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $style); // CSS comments; works SUCCESSFULLY if run inline
```

it works and the output file is written. Only when I pass it through the function does it fail with 0 bytes.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel—shell out to a proper minifier.

Answer (score 2):

The `minify` function appears to work fine when called without the `global` and the `output buffer` references.

The source file used for the test was 983 lines long with several comments - this was reduced to a single ( very long ) line with no comments very quickly ( actually took between approx 0.002s and 0.005s over several tests )

```
<?php

    # Test file located in same directory as this PHP script
    $file=__DIR__ . '/test-source.css';
    $target=__DIR__ . '/test-output.css';

    
    function minify($data) { 
        $data = preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $data);
        $data = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t", '  ', '    ', '    '), '', $data); 
        return $data;
    }
    
    $css=minify( file_get_contents( $file ) );
    file_put_contents( $target, $css );
?>
```

Comment: That works! I still don't get why my original method to pass $style to the function failed, but that is not so important as having a way that works. I will be combining multiple files and tested by adding a second line like "$css.=minify( file_get_contents( $file2 ) ); This works too. Thx much.